# panda python groupby depending on other list

Tags: python, pandas

I have x an y of my cars and would like to add a new column with the block of the car (1-3). The "y_block_number_ends" gives the y coordinates where a block ends.

```
import pandas as pd

x_start = 1
y_start = 1
size_city = 5

y_block_number_ends = [2,4]

cars = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.repeat(np.arange(x_start,x_start+size_city),size_city),
                    'y': np.tile(np.arange(y_start,y_start+size_city),size_city)})

#cars['block_y']= cars.where([cars['y'] > 0 | (cars['y'] <= 2)])

print(cars)
```

the new dataframe would look like this

```
    x  y    block
0   1  1      1
1   1  2      1
2   1  3      2
3   1  4      2
4   1  5      3
5   2  1      1
6   2  2      1
7   2  3      2
8   2  4      2
9   2  5      3
10  3  1      1
11  3  2      1
12  3  3      2
13  3  4      2
14  3  5      3
15  4  1      1
16  4  2      1
17  4  3      2
18  4  4      2
19  4  5      3
20  5  1      1
21  5  2      1
22  5  3      2
23  5  4      2
24  5  5      3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `pd.cut`

```
cars.assign(block=pd.cut(cars.y, [0, 2, 4, float('inf')], labels=[1, 2, 3]))

    x  y block
0   1  1     1
1   1  2     1
2   1  3     2
3   1  4     2
4   1  5     3
5   2  1     1
6   2  2     1
7   2  3     2
8   2  4     2
9   2  5     3
10  3  1     1
11  3  2     1
12  3  3     2
13  3  4     2
14  3  5     3
15  4  1     1
16  4  2     1
17  4  3     2
18  4  4     2
19  4  5     3
20  5  1     1
21  5  2     1
22  5  3     2
23  5  4     2
24  5  5     3
```

---

#### `searchsorted`

```
ends = np.array([2, 4])
labels = np.array([1, 2, 3])
cars.assign(block=labels[ends.searchsorted(cars.y)])

    x  y  block
0   1  1      1
1   1  2      1
2   1  3      2
3   1  4      2
4   1  5      3
5   2  1      1
6   2  2      1
7   2  3      2
8   2  4      2
9   2  5      3
10  3  1      1
11  3  2      1
12  3  3      2
13  3  4      2
14  3  5      3
15  4  1      1
16  4  2      1
17  4  3      2
18  4  4      2
19  4  5      3
20  5  1      1
21  5  2      1
22  5  3      2
23  5  4      2
24  5  5      3
```

Comment: Entirely up to you, but it may be useful to others to include `float("inf")` or `np.inf` as the right side of the last bin for your `pd.cut` example instead of 1000.

Comment: I debated that in my head for a grand total of 5 seconds.... but you are right /-:

Comment: I know I am totaly outing me as a newbe saying this, but.. thank you for introducing me to assign. For some reason I still can't get it to work, when I print the cars dataFrame after this line of code i still only get the x and y columns. Any ideas?

Comment: `assign` creates a copy of the dataframe.  You'll want to `cars = cars.assign(block=labels[ends.searchsorted(cars.y)])`  I use it this way for several reasons (all subjective).  One, when I'm answering questions, I'd like my answer not to alter the state of the dataframe the question presents.  If the asker wants to change their dataframe, they can make the assignment back themselves.  Two, I like the way it looks.  Three, I can do fun things like `df.assign(**df.select_dtypes(np.number).mul(2))`

Comment: @JohannaMarklund Also, you are not outing yourself.  Many people are unaware of `assign`.  I'm not seeing `pd.DataFrame.query`, `pd.DataFrame.eval`, or `pd.DataFrame.align` used much either.  Those are other cool methods as well.

Comment: Thank you sooo much.   The assign comand is great! I will look into the eval and align, query I have already used.